# How do I get mod_userdir to work without a trailing slash?

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration

(My apologies if this is in the wrong place or has already been asked.)

I've just set up an Apache webserver and am having headaches with UserDir and trailing slashes.  The UserDir directive is just:

```
UserDir public_html
```

And it works for `http://www.example.com/~user/` but not, as far as I can tell, for `http://www.example.com/~user`.  What seems to happen is that it gets sent to `DocumentRoot/~user` which then eats it up (the stuff in `DocumentRoot` has its own set of what-to-dos for files that don't exist, just in case that's important, so as far as Apache is concerned *something* does *something* with the request).

Is there a way to make `http://www.example.com/~user` work via mod_userdir, or does it need another level of processing first?  If so, what?

**Edit:** A little experimenting, and comparing with another system where it does work, led me to add the rule:

```
RedirectMatch /~user$ /~user/
```

to the `.htaccess` in `user/public_html`.  So it looks as though the request `http://www.example.com/~user` *is* getting passed to the user's directory, but then it doesn't find anything to match and so sends it back to the server saying "I can't find anything, take a look in `DocumentRoot`.".  So it seems to be a strange incantation of the "trailing slashes" issue.  I had thought to fix trailing slashes with a bit of `mod_rewrite` trickery, but I couldn't find a set of rules that would match `/~user`.  So the problem appears to be that the request `http://www.example.com/~user` does not get matched to `/home/user/public_html/index.html` whilst `http://www.example.com/~user/` does.

Refined question: Is there a server configuration that will fix this match, or is the `RedirectMatch` rule the simplest method?

Comment: Do you have any rewrite rules? UserDir should work without the trailing slash.

Comment: @Pablo: The only configuration thing I did was to change the DocumentRoot.  The DR has some fancy stuff in its `.htaccess` but surely it shouldn't get there because the UserDir should kick in first.  (A little more experimenting has led to some new data, but I'll edit that in to the question.)